# Sleeping Issues

Tags: single-word-requests

Many a time while travelling, I fall asleep and then my head starts falling. I immediately  wake up with this but then go back to sleep again, and this keeps repeating.

What is this known as, “falling of head while sleeping”?

Answer (score 4):

Nodding-off or to nod-off sounds about [right](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nodding+off):

> 2. To let the head fall forward when sleepy.

Not exactly one word, but might still be wroth using.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a *hypnic jerk*, where *hypnic* is a fairly uncommon word meaning sleep.  It is derived from Greek *ὑπνικός*, because in Greek mythology [*Ὕπνος* was the personification of Sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnos), Death’s gentler brother.  Sleep-inducing medications are sometimes called *hypnotic* ones for this reason.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnic_jerk) provides several synonyms for hypnic jerks:

> A *hypnic jerk, hypnagogic jerk, sleep start, sleep twitch,* or *night start* is an involuntary twitch which occurs just as a person is beginning to fall asleep, often causing them to awaken suddenly for a moment.

Hypnic jerks should be confused with hippie jerks :)

Regarding the <sub><sup>HYPNO-</sup></sub> prefix, the OED reports that:

> The compounds in Greek were not numerous, and all those employed in English are new formations, and chiefly pathological terms.

Here are a few of them that it mentions:

- ‖ hypna [n. pl.] ← ‖ hypnum [n.]
- hypnaesˈthesic [adj.] ← hypnaesthesis
- ‖ hypnaesthesis [n.]
- hypnagogic [adj.]
- hypnaˈgogically [adv.]
- ‖ ˈhypnale [n.]
- hypnic [adj.]
- hypno- [pref.]
- hypnoanalysis [n.]
- hypnoˈanalyst ← hypnoanalysis
- ˌhypnoanaˈlytic [adj.] ← hypnoanalysis
- ˈhypnobate ← hypno-
- hypnocyst ← hypno-
- hypnodylic [adj.] ← hypno-
- hypnoˈgenesis [adj. n.] ← hypno-
- hypnogeˈnetically [adv.] ← hypno-
- × hypnogogic → hypnagogic
- hypnoid [adj.1]
- hypnoid [adj.2]
- hypˈnoidal [adj.] ← hypnoid
- hypˈnologist ← hypno-
- hypˈnology [adj. n.] ← hypno-
- hypnone [n.]
- hypnopaedia [n.]
- hypnoˈpaedic [adj.] ← hypnopaedia
- hypnoˈpaedically [adv.] ← hypnopaedia
- hypnophilous [adj.]
- hypnoˈphobia [adj.] ← hypno-
- hypnopompic [adj.]
- Hypnos [n.]
- ˈhypnoscope ← hypno-
- hypnosis [n.]
- hypˈnosophist ← hypno-
- hypˈnosophy ← hypno-
- ˈhypnosperm ← hypno-
- hypnoˈsporic [adj.] ← hypno-
- ˌhypnotheraˈpeutic [adj.] ← hypnotherapy
- ˌhypnotheraˈpeutically [adv.] ← hypnotherapy
- hypnoˈtherapist ← hypnotherapy
- hypnotherapy [n.]
- hypnotic [adj.]
- † hypnotical [adj.]
- hypˈnotically [adv.] ← hypnotical
- hypnotism [n.]
- hypnotist [n.]
- hypnoˈtistic [adj.] ← hypnotist
- hypnotizability ← hypnotize
- ˈhypnotizable [adj.] ← hypnotize
- hypnotiˈzation ← hypnotize
- hypnotize [v.]
- ˈhypnotized [ppl. adj.] ← hypnotize
- ˈhypnotizer ← hypnotize
- ˈhypnotizing [vbl. n.] ← hypnotize
- hypnotoid [adj.]
- ‖ hypnum [n.]
- ‖ hypnums [n. pl.] ← ‖ hypnum [n.]

Comment: Incidentally, "hypnopompic" can refer to jerks or tics that occur as one is waking up, as opposed to when one is falling asleep.